# How to make sure certificate is not changed?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

There is an issue came into my mind.
Is there any common way to make an app running only when there is an installed certificate in the system. And I want such a certificate to be issued and verified by my self-signed certificate?

I can get a certificate by it's name from the storage, but how do I make sure such a certificate is signed by my self-signed certificate and nobody have issued a certificate with the same name and replaced the one in the local storage?

Or in other words, how do I make sure the certificate which signed the certificate at local storage is not a forged one?

I'm sorry if its not correct and|or clear question, but I'll be happy to have help regarding it.

Comment: Maybe take a look at: [What is certificate pinning?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/29988)

Comment: But how do I make sure, that public key my soft get from store is signed ULTIMATELY BY MY {root | intermediate} certificate a public key from which is in customer's Trusted Root Certification Authority store???

In other words, how do I make sure [public cert B] is signed by [private cert A] using [public cert A]???

Comment: I will update my answer in 30 minutes

Comment: Couldn't but will. You may want to check the bouncy castle c# library by the way.

Comment: @Anatolyevich. I came up with the solution. I hope this will solve your problem. Actually, that is a very fair question to ask, and I would expect to achieve such a trivial task more easily. You can still go for the BouncyCastle library which is ported to C# from Java.

Comment: @Anatolyevich, I miss-used the word trivial. It should have been the exact opposite, crucial. What I actually wanted to say is (but stack overflow doesn't let me edit my comment one more time), this is so crucial a task, and so common, that there should have been a very easy way to achieve it, like this easy: issuerCert.VerifyCertificate(clientCert);

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and all the answers. At the moment I'm busy, but will take my time this evening to go through the code you've provided and compare it with the one I came up with tomorrow (I took your original code as the base for that and it looks way easier and more clear comparing with the current one). 
And I hope we'll come-up with the best solution for the scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good question indeed.

There is always a possibility of the end-user creating a valid certificate chain with your subject name and as the issuer, another for the issuer ceritificate, all up to the root.

What they canot do is to sign those certifcates with the issuer certificate's private key.

Therefore, the code below loads the application certificate from the personal certificate store of the current user, then, loads the issuer certificate of the issuer from the resources and verifies the signature on the application certificate installed on the client machine using the public key of the issuer certificate.

In my source code, the issuer certificate is added to the resources with the key IssuerCertificate

I am actually fond of coming out with a solution like this.

In the code I mention an encoding ASN.1. [Check it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) if you need

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string expectedSubjectName = "My Application";
    X509Certificate2 issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Resource1.IssuerCertificate);
    string expectedIssuerName = issuerCertificate.Subject;

    bool result = VerifyCertificateIssuer(expectedSubjectName, expectedIssuerName, issuerCertificate);
}

private static void ThrowCertificateNotFoundException(string expectedSubjectName, string expectedIssuerName, bool isThumbprintMismatch)
{
    if (isThumbprintMismatch)
    {
        // Notification for possible certificate forgery
    }
    throw new SecurityException("A certificate with subject name " + expectedSubjectName + " issued by " + expectedIssuerName + " is required to run this application");
}

private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string expectedSubjectName, string expectedIssuerName)
{
    X509Store personalCertificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    personalCertificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    X509CertificateCollection certificatesBySubjectName = personalCertificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, expectedSubjectName, true);

    if (certificatesBySubjectName.Count == 0)
    {
        ThrowCertificateNotFoundException(expectedSubjectName, expectedIssuerName, false);
    }

    X509Certificate2 matchingCertificate = null;

    foreach (X509Certificate2 certificateBySubjectName in certificatesBySubjectName)
    {
        if (certificateBySubjectName.Issuer == expectedIssuerName)
        {
            matchingCertificate = certificateBySubjectName;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchingCertificate == null)
    {
        ThrowCertificateNotFoundException(expectedSubjectName, expectedIssuerName, false);
    }

    return matchingCertificate;
}

private static bool VerifyCertificateIssuer(string expectedSubjectName, string expectedIssuerName, X509Certificate2 issuerCertificate)
{
    X509Certificate2 matchingCertificate = GetCertificate(expectedSubjectName, expectedIssuerName);

    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.Build(matchingCertificate);

    // bool x = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate.RawData) == Encoding.ASCII.GetString(issuerCertificate.RawData);

    byte[] certificateData = matchingCertificate.RawData;

    MemoryStream asn1Stream = new MemoryStream(certificateData);
    BinaryReader asn1StreamReader = new BinaryReader(asn1Stream);

    // The der encoded certificate structure is like this:
    // Root Sequence
    //     Sequence (Certificate Content)
    //     Sequence (Signature Algorithm (like SHA256withRSAEncryption)
    //     Sequence (Signature)

    // We need to decode the ASN.1 content to get
    //     Sequence 0 (which is the actual certificate content that is signed by the issuer, including the sequence definition and tag number and length)
    //     Sequence 2 (which is the signature. X509Certificate2 class does not give us that information. The year is 2015)

    // Read the root sequence (ignore)
    byte leadingOctet = asn1StreamReader.ReadByte();
    ReadTagNumber(leadingOctet, asn1StreamReader);
    ReadDataLength(asn1StreamReader);

    // Save the current position because we will need it for including the sequence header with the certificate content
    int sequence0StartPosition = (int)asn1Stream.Position;

    leadingOctet = asn1StreamReader.ReadByte();
    ReadTagNumber(leadingOctet, asn1StreamReader);
    int sequence0ContentLength = ReadDataLength(asn1StreamReader);
    int sequence0HeaderLength = (int)asn1Stream.Position - sequence0StartPosition;
    sequence0ContentLength += sequence0HeaderLength;
    byte[] sequence0Content = new byte[sequence0ContentLength];
    asn1Stream.Position -= 4;
    asn1StreamReader.Read(sequence0Content, 0, sequence0ContentLength);

    // Skip sequence 1 (signature algorithm) since we don't need it and assume that we know it because we own the issuer certificate
    // This sequence, containing the algorithm used during the signing process IS HIDDEN FROM US BY DEFAULT. The year is 2015.
    // What should have been done for real is, to get the algorithm ID (hash algorithm and asymmetric algorithm) and to use those
    // algorithms during the verification process
    leadingOctet = asn1StreamReader.ReadByte();
    ReadTagNumber(leadingOctet, asn1StreamReader);
    int sequence1ContentLength = ReadDataLength(asn1StreamReader);
    byte[] sequence1Content = new byte[sequence1ContentLength];
    asn1StreamReader.Read(sequence1Content, 0, sequence1ContentLength);

    // Read sequence 2 (signature)
    // The actual signature of the certificate IS HIDDEN FROM US BY DEFAULT. The year is 2015.
    leadingOctet = asn1StreamReader.ReadByte();
    ReadTagNumber(leadingOctet, asn1StreamReader);
    int sequence2ContentLength = ReadDataLength(asn1StreamReader);
    byte unusedBits = asn1StreamReader.ReadByte();
    sequence2ContentLength -= 1;
    byte[] sequence2Content = new byte[sequence2ContentLength];
    asn1StreamReader.Read(sequence2Content, 0, sequence2ContentLength);

    // At last, we have the data that is signed and the signature.
    bool verificationResult = ((RSACryptoServiceProvider)issuerCertificate.PublicKey.Key)
    .VerifyData
    (
        sequence0Content,
        CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"),
        sequence2Content
    );

    return verificationResult;
}

private static byte[] ReadTagNumber(byte leadingOctet, BinaryReader inputStreamReader)
{
    List<byte> byts = new List<byte>();
    byte temporaryByte;
    if ((leadingOctet & 0x1F) == 0x1F) // More than 1 byte is used to specify the tag number
    {
        while (((temporaryByte = inputStreamReader.ReadByte()) & 0x80) > 0)
        {
            byts.Add((byte)(temporaryByte & 0x7F));
        }
        byts.Add(temporaryByte);
    }
    else
    {
        byts.Add((byte)(leadingOctet & 0x1F));
    }
    return byts.ToArray();
}

private static int ReadDataLength(BinaryReader inputStreamReader)
{
    byte leadingOctet = inputStreamReader.ReadByte();
    if ((leadingOctet & 0x80) > 0)
    {
        int subsequentialOctetsCount = leadingOctet & 0x7F;
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < subsequentialOctetsCount; i++)
        {
            length <<= 8;
            length += inputStreamReader.ReadByte();
        }
        return length;
    }
    else
    {
        return leadingOctet;
    }
}

private static byte[] GetTagNumber(byte leadingOctet, BinaryReader inputStreamReader, ref int readBytes)
{
    List<byte> byts = new List<byte>();
    byte temporaryByte;
    if ((leadingOctet & 0x1F) == 0x1F) // More than 1 byte is used to specify the tag number
    {
        while (((temporaryByte = inputStreamReader.ReadByte()) & 0x80) > 0)
        {
            readBytes++;
            byts.Add((byte)(temporaryByte & 0x7F));
        }
        byts.Add(temporaryByte);
    }
    else
    {
        byts.Add((byte)(leadingOctet & 0x1F));
    }
    return byts.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Just went through the code you posted. Seems like it's exactly what I was looking for.
Great thanks for your help.

Comment: And I feel I'm kinda newbie in certs thing.. How does this code ensure the certificate with expectedSubjectName is signed exactly by existing in system expectedIssuerName certificate?? By personalCertificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, expectedSubjectName, true)?

Comment: Actually, I am going to update my answer. I am in a meeting now, but will update it as soon as possible to REALLY check whether the certificate has changed or not using X590Chain class

Comment: I have just checked the scenario when user creates personal certificate with the same name, import in in storage and finally the storage has 2 certificates with the same name in trusted root certificates authorities(TRCA).. 
As a result, the user can issue fake certificate, sign it with previously created certificate and it will be accepted by software because yes, there is original certificate in storage.. and fake certificate is valid (because it's issuer public key is imported in TRCA.

Is there any way to get some sort of fingerprint data of issuer certificate from child certificate?

Comment: I appreciate. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Yes. Finally. Editing my answer now.

Comment: Another way of doing this couldbe; Windows creates a thumbprint for all the certificates using SHA1. You can access this using clientCertificate.Thumbprint;. If you build the chain for the client certificate and get the chain element at location 1 (The issuer on the client system) and compare the thumbprint of this certificate with the thumbprint of your original issuer certificate, you can make sure that the issuer certificate on the client system is the same with your original. Then you can rely on the result of clientCertificate.Verify();

Comment: Went through the code and it's tought... Takes all the data from very bottom which is cool.. 
And yestarday I came up with the following decision:

1) take a certificate from storage by it's name
2) call X509Chain.Build for that certificate
3) Take X509Chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
4) Compare string from {3} to the hardcoded in software public key string from my root certificate.
5) If all the steps succeeded, then the certificate is valid. Othervise it's not.

There are some minor issues in such the way, but I believe it's good one too.
Any Ideas about it?

Comment: If the public key of the certificate at position 1 checks with your original's and clientCert.Verify() works for the client certificate then, I think Yes.. (but after checking the scenario as you did earlier). By the way, I think I'm the first person to implement this without BouncyCastle :) I saw the same, or similar questions on forums, some never get answered, some never solved..

Comment: Yep.. We are getting more and more related of libs and frameworks. Hence the unresolved questions.. 
And the less people remember, the more respect you have, my friend.. ;)
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It was nice meeting you and talking to you my friend :) You're welcome.